# Create new key value in JSON data using Python / Pandas?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to work with the Campaign Monitor API, posting JSON data through the API to update subscriber lists. I'm currently one change away from being able to send data,

Right now, my JSON data looks like this

```
{
            "EmailAddress": "subscriber1@example.com",
            "Name": "New Subscriber One",
            "CustomFields": [
                {
                    "Key": "website",
                    "Value": "http://example.com"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "interests",
                    "Value": "magic"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "interests",
                    "Value": "romantic walks"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "age",
                    "Value": "",
                    "Clear": true
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "EmailAddress": "subscriber2@example.com",
            "Name": "New Subscriber Two",
        },
        {
            "EmailAddress": "subscriber3@example.com",
            "Name": "New Subscriber Three",
        }
}
```

I still need to add a new key value at the beginning of the JSON payload, incorporating the 'Subscribers' : my_json_data. How would I go about easily adding on the Subscribers key and placing my full and current json data into a list?

Final result should look like

```
{
      'Subscribers' : [
      {
            "EmailAddress": "subscriber1@example.com",
            "Name": "New Subscriber One",
            "CustomFields": [
                {
                    "Key": "website",
                    "Value": "http://example.com"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "interests",
                    "Value": "magic"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "interests",
                    "Value": "romantic walks"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "age",
                    "Value": "",
                    "Clear": true
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "EmailAddress": "subscriber2@example.com",
            "Name": "New Subscriber Two",
        },
        {
            "EmailAddress": "subscriber3@example.com",
            "Name": "New Subscriber Three",
        }
   }
                   ]
}
```

I've tried to approach this with creating a new dictionary however when I convert that back to JSON I get more issues and headaches. Is there any easy way to keep everything as a JSON formatted dataset and add in the leading 'Subscribers' key?

Comment: your `JSON` is invalid.

Comment: What is invalid about it? The JSON is provided as an example from the API documentation,

Comment: try validating your `JSON` format with online validators.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it assuming you've got a valid `JSON`.

```
your_new_json = {}
your_new_json['Subscribers'] = [your_current_json]
```